# How to mount a raspberry pi case above an analog thermometer dial

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I need help with ideas on how to mount a case, that contains a Raspberry Pi zero and a camera, over an analog thermometer dial (see photos below). Additionally, there will be a power bank, as well, but its position isn't much important. I am not an engineer and would appreciate any ideas how to mount the Pi above the dial.

What I have:

- Raspberry Pi Zero in the case. There is a noIR camera inside (see the hole on the photo, photo isn't mine).
- Thermometer will be in a compost pile in a vertical position. The dial will be facing up. It has a frame around it (see the orange thing on the photo).
- The round frame has 12.4cm diameter (outer edge) and 7.5mm thickness.
- A cron job in the Pi runs a python script periodically which takes a photo of the thermometer dial.
- Raspberry Pi is powered by a power bank.

Requirements:

- The case has to be mounted on that round frame (see orange thing on photo) so that the camera is directed to the thermometer dial, and has to be at some distance (about 10cm) so that the focus is clear.
- The case has to be stable and not slip or fall off the round frame.
- The case can be disconnected and then put back on at the end of the day.
- It's a one time project, so the solution can be something makeshift.
- Optionally: any ideas how to mount a power bank, as well, so that it can be easily unmounted for charging and mounted back?

Please share your ideas on mounting all these together.

I found one thing on Amazon that could work but I'm afraid it would slip and rotate because there would be only one point of contact. Can be found by "Camera Mount Clamp Stand with Double Ballhead and Crab Clamp".

I think to make it really stable there should be 3 points of contact instead of one, something like a mini-tripod hovering over the center and its legs are on the frame, but tripods usually have things mounted on top.

Thermometer:
[image: Thermometer and the frame]

Raspberry Pi case:
[image: Raspberry Pi case]

Comment: A camera tripod with tilt and rotate.

Comment: interior or exterior location?

Comment: @Pete W, the whole pile including the Pi will be covered by waterproof tarp

Comment: @Solar Mike, thanks. How would you mount tripod's legs to the thermometer frame?

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea, that, while not sturdy, will work fine, very cheap, and the only tool required would be scissors.

What you'd need is a broad strip of PET plastic (the type used in plastic bottles, or transparent packaging - "windows" on toy boxes to see the toy inside, slightly sturdier document sleeves, laminated paper documents etc. It has just enough flex it can be folded as you like, and is thin enough to be cut with scissor.

Make an inverse U shaped "bridge" between the two vertical supports of the wheel; two parallel length-wise cuts near the middle will provide a holder to hold the Pi case in place, and pairs of cuts near the ends will latch onto the wheel to prevent it from tilting.

[image]

Comment: Great idea. Where can I buy such plastic?

Comment: In "one-off" amounts? Probably the easiest approach is to "prototype" the solution in cardboard, then get the strip of cardboard laminated at a local print shop. Alternatively cut up a big (5l) plastic bottle, or visit the local mall and look for products (gifts, kitchen utensils, tools etc) packaged in this sort of plastic.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the most practical solution -- if you have a 3d printer large enough (which shouldn't be too difficult) -- is to create a mount with two or three legs ending.  Each leg should have a clip retainer like the following:

[image]

**Figure: (source: Pinterest)**

This can be easily removed on and off.

Comment: This is a great idea, thank you. Considering my zero knowledge of 3d printing and limited time (need to finish in 1 week), it's not going to work for me. But it's a good option for the next project.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a lot of velcro straps at home, and this light cheap plastic tripod, so I ended up with this:

[image]